# How to add Guava lib to runtime classpath in Intellij idea

Tags: intellij-idea, guava, noclassdeffounderror

I am trying to make use of Guava in an Intellij Gradle project and although my code compiles, at runtime I am seeing this >

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/Ordering

I have read a number of posts suggesting that the Guava lib is not on the classpath at runtime. I have verified this by writing the classpath out using System.getProperty("java.class.path") and the Guava lib is not there.

I have tried (as others have suggested) to add either the folder or the lib itself as a Module dependency with scope = compile. See image >

[Intellij Module Dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xGai.png)
This also has not worked.

Here are the libs used in the project >
[Project Libs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vV2j2.png)

Any advice on what is going on here gratefully accepted.

My build.gradle >

```
group 'EE'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

It contains no reference to the guava lib I added to the Project Libraries:: com.google.guava:guava:18.02

Looks like I have missed an important step somewhere.

Comment: You might find it easier to just write a POM for your project and have intellij use that. Then you don't have to fiddle with any of that and the project is easily portable to other IDEs (or no IDE).

Comment: All the dependencies in the Gradle project must be defined inside `build.gradle` file, any changes you make in IntelliJ IDEA module dependencies will be discarded on the next Gradle project refresh. Please show the relevant part of your `build.gradle` file and what Guava library version you are using.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that but I really want this to work with Gradle.

Comment: After reading another post that directly modified build.gradle I got past the problem by adding this > compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '18.0' to my build.gradle. Don't know if that is the right way it should be done.

Comment: That is correct. `compile` is for compilation/runtime dependencies of the main application. `testCompile` is dependencies needed to compile and run the tests.

Comment: Unrelated, but your version is 18 while the current one is 22, so yours is at least two years old (and you're on Java 8, so you need no old Java 7 compatible version). If you're starting a new project, I'd suggest to pick the newest stable versions of everything as this minimizes the overhead when adding more libraries and/or upgrading them.

Answer (score 0):

Per official documentation from Guava.

https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/UseGuavaInYourBuild

Add the line below to your build.gradle file dependencies section:

```
dependencies {
  compile group: 'com.google.guava', 
  name: 'guava', 
  version: '23.5-jre' # or 23.5-android for the Android flavor
}
```